# iptables doesn't filter my ssh failed logins any more

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, iptables, login, firewall

I have a rule on iptables to block too many failed attempted logins on ssh. On my new server however it seems not to work any more, in the sense that I can still login straight away even if I fail for 10 times:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53300 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --rsource
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53300 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 --name DEFAULT --rsource -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53300 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -L -v

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 17 packets, 796 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2   120            tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:53300 state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:53300 state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 4 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
   42  6906 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:53300

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 59 packets, 6974 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

(53300 is the non-default port of my SSH server)

What could make iptables not to work as desired ? Ubuntu 20.04, iptables 1.8.4

Comment: You might not like this answer, but iptables is rather low level. Take a look at https://shorewall.org/ . It's a higher level  tool to set netfilter (so also iptables). It's backwards compatible with itself, so It keep working when iptables is updated.

Comment: You might not like my answer either, but I would rather use a tool like [CSF+LFD](https://configserver.com/cp/csf.html) or [Fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which in my opinion is more flexible and more reliable. It works by 'tailing' log files in real time and bans offending IP address at firewall level. So you'll still be using `iptables`. If you still have problems have a look at the **log files** (syslog).

Comment: I agree with Garo and Anonymous. My vote goes to Fail2ban

Answer (score 1):

It does actually works.

Simply I was counting the password attempts, while what `hit_count` actually counts here is the time you have to start connecting again because you misspelled too many times the password (and this is in turn configurable in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as `MaxAuthTries`)